# Translation Import Membership in navigation menu

Tags: translation

(version 5.18.4 - Joomla with multilingual Dutch)

In the navigation menu under Memberships there is the menu-item Import Membership. I think it must be Import Memberships. When i change it with: Admin Navigation Menu to add the 's', the item Import Memberships is translated.

In civicrm_data.tpl it is Import Membership, but in menu.po Import Memberships.

Comment: That's odd because on the public demo https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org it does have the "s".

Comment: Yes, in the sandbox is it with met the 's'. Maybe it is because i have an old version many times upgraded and i should try a fresh installation to see if the civicrm_data.nl_NL.mysql puts the good value in the table.